# Change language of camera roll's cancel button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a app to take photo from `iphone` camera or choose one picture from camera roll, my problem is app default language is Portuguese but camera roll text appear in English.

How could I customize it?

Comment: Is your phone's primary language set to Portuguese?

Comment: Yes, and i set Localization native development region = pt

Answer (score 3):

To resolve my problem, i just added on "localizations" of my project info tab a new language "Portuguese".